# Simplifying some jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a map whereby when a region is clicked, a `div` relating to that region appears below the map. For the purposes of this it has been simplified.

Basically, I have the jQuery code sorted, but it is enormously long and clumsy - I'm pretty sure there's a simpler and easier way of doing this.

http://jsfiddle.net/rupfield23/nBb7g/3/

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="sh_north-america">North America Image</a><br>
<a href="#" id="sh_south-america">South America Image</a><br>
<a href="#" id="sh_europe">Europe Image</a><br>
<a href="#" id="sh_africa">Africa Image</a><br>
<a href="#" id="sh_middle-east">Middle East Image</a><br>
<a href="#" id="sh_western-asia">Western Asia Image</a><br>
<a href="#" id="sh_far-east">Far East Image</a><br>
<a href="#" id="sh_australasia">Australasia Image</a>


<div id="list_north-america">North America List</div>
<div id="list_south-america">South America List</div>
<div id="list_europe">Europe List</div>
<div id="list_africa">Africa List</div>
<div id="list_middle-east">Middle East List</div>
<div id="list_western-asia">Western Asia List</div>
<div id="list_far-east">Far East List</div>
<div id="list_australasia">Australasia List</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#list_north-america').hide();
$('#list_south-america').hide();
$('#list_europe').hide();
$('#list_africa').hide();
$('#list_middle-east').hide();
$('#list_western-asia').hide();
$('#list_far-east').hide();
$('#list_australasia').hide();



$('#sh_north-america').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();$('#list_north-america').fadeIn();$('#map').addClass('expand');});
$('#list_north-america').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
$(document).click(function(){$('#list_north-america').fadeOut();$('#map').removeClass('expand');});
$('#sh_south-america').click(function(){$('#list_north-america').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_europe').click(function(){$('#list_north-america').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_africa').click(function(){$('#list_north-america').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_middle-east').click(function(){$('#list_north-america').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_western-asia').click(function(){$('#list_north-america').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_far-east').click(function(){$('#list_north-america').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_australasia').click(function(){$('#list_north-america').fadeOut();});

$('#sh_south-america').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();$('#list_south-america').fadeIn();$('#map').addClass('expand');});
$('#list_south-america').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
$(document).click(function(){$('#list_south-america').fadeOut();$('#map').removeClass('expand');});
$('#sh_north-america').click(function(){$('#list_south-america').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_europe').click(function(){$('#list_south-america').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_africa').click(function(){$('#list_south-america').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_middle-east').click(function(){$('#list_south-america').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_western-asia').click(function(){$('#list_south-america').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_far-east').click(function(){$('#list_south-america').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_australasia').click(function(){$('#list_south-america').fadeOut();});

$('#sh_europe').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();$('#list_europe').fadeIn();$('#map').addClass('expand');});
$('#list_europe').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
$(document).click(function(){$('#list_europe').fadeOut();$('#map').removeClass('expand');});
$('#sh_north-america').click(function(){$('#list_europe').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_south-america').click(function(){$('#list_europe').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_africa').click(function(){$('#list_europe').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_middle-east').click(function(){$('#list_europe').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_western-asia').click(function(){$('#list_europe').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_far-east').click(function(){$('#list_europe').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_australasia').click(function(){$('#list_europe').fadeOut();});

$('#sh_africa').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();$('#list_africa').fadeIn();$('#map').addClass('expand');});
$('#list_africa').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
$(document).click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();$('#map').removeClass('expand');});
$('#sh_north-america').click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_south-america').click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_europe').click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_middle-east').click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_western-asia').click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_far-east').click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_australasia').click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();});

$('#sh_middle-east').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();$('#list_middle-east').fadeIn();$('#map').addClass('expand');});
$('#list_middle-east').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
$(document).click(function(){$('#list_middle-east').fadeOut();$('#map').removeClass('expand');});
$('#sh_north-america').click(function(){$('#list_middle-east').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_south-america').click(function(){$('#list_middle-east').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_europe').click(function(){$('#list_middle-east').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_africa').click(function(){$('#list_middle-east').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_western-asia').click(function(){$('#list_middle-east').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_far-east').click(function(){$('#list_middle-east').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_australasia').click(function(){$('#list_middle-east').fadeOut();});

$('#sh_western-asia').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();$('#list_western-asia').fadeIn();$('#map').addClass('expand');});
$('#list_western-asia').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
$(document).click(function(){$('#list_western-asia').fadeOut();$('#map').removeClass('expand');});
$('#sh_north-america').click(function(){$('#list_western-asia').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_south-america').click(function(){$('#list_western-asia').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_europe').click(function(){$('#list_western-asia').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_africa').click(function(){$('#list_western-asia').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_middle-east').click(function(){$('#list_western-asia').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_far-east').click(function(){$('#list_western-asia').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_australasia').click(function(){$('#list_western-asia').fadeOut();});

$('#sh_far-east').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();$('#list_far-east').fadeIn();$('#map').addClass('expand');});
$('#list_far-east').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
$(document).click(function(){$('#list_far-east').fadeOut();$('#map').removeClass('expand');});
$('#sh_north-america').click(function(){$('#list_far-east').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_south-america').click(function(){$('#list_far-east').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_europe').click(function(){$('#list_far-east').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_africa').click(function(){$('#list_far-east').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_middle-east').click(function(){$('#list_far-east').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_western-asia').click(function(){$('#list_far-east').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_australasia').click(function(){$('#list_far-east').fadeOut();});

$('#sh_australasia').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();$('#list_australasia').fadeIn();$('#map').addClass('expand');});
$('#list_australasia').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
$(document).click(function(){$('#list_australasia').fadeOut();$('#map').removeClass('expand');});
$('#sh_north-america').click(function(){$('#list_australasia').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_south-america').click(function(){$('#list_australasia').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_europe').click(function(){$('#list_australasia').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_africa').click(function(){$('#list_australasia').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_middle-east').click(function(){$('#list_australasia').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_western-asia').click(function(){$('#list_australasia').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_far-east').click(function(){$('#list_australasia').fadeOut();});
```

Thanks!

Comment: add classes to all of them, and assign your event handler once per class.

Comment: Reviews belong on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @turtlebyte Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/8pARv/) just tell me what to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use more general selectors, I think you can eliminate a lot of duplicated code in your example.  I made a quick pass and came up with this:

```
$('div[id^=list_]').hide();

$('[id^=sh_]').click(function (e) {
    var list = $('#list_' + e.target.id.slice(3));
    e.stopPropagation();
    list.fadeIn();
    $('[id^=list_]').not(list).fadeOut();
    $('#map').addClass('expand');
});

$('[id^=list_]').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function () {
    $('[id^=list_]').fadeOut();
    $('#map').removeClass('expand');
});
```

You may be able to optimize further.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XcBMB/).

Answer (score 0):

No one here is likely to go over everything for you, but I'll just give one example of how to make it shorter.

You have this code in one section..

```
$('#sh_north-america').click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_south-america').click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_europe').click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_middle-east').click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_western-asia').click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_far-east').click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();});
$('#sh_australasia').click(function(){$('#list_africa').fadeOut();});
```

give all these id's the same class in the html... lets say class="regions-2". So you could make the above code this short, very easily.

```
$('.regions-2').click(function(){
    $('#list_africa').fadeOut();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unique `<div>` tag, and by clicking one of the above links you modify the content of the `<div>` with text function.

Answer (score 0):

I gave you a quick jsFiddle that might help.  Notice the key to my version is having the mapping in the IDs with this line

```
var country = linkObj.attr('id').split('_').pop();
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/nBb7g/4/